# Confusion about the definition of Plancherel measure for finite groups

Tags: representation-theory, definition, harmonic-analysis

I have confusion about the definition of Plancerel measure for finite groups. Let $G$ be a finite group.

In the following link we see that the Plancherel measure on $\hat G$ is given by $\mu(\pi)=\dim(\pi)$ where $\dim(\pi)$ denotes the dimension of the irreducible representation $\pi$

http://www.stieltjes.org/archief/rep9899/node13.html

On the other hand, in wikipedia, it is given by $\mu(\pi)=\frac{(\dim(\pi))^2}{|G|}$ 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_measure

Why are the results different? Which problem should I consider to compute the Plancherel measure for finite group? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly the first of your sources gives a result intelligible to me: in the decomposition of the regular repn, every irreducible occurs with multiplicity equal to its dimension. The second version has the property that it sums to $1$ for finite groups, but otherwise I don't understand the sense of it. That particular Wiki article has an unusual context for discussion of Plancherel/spectral measure, also, and in fact does not quite say _precisely_ what they mean by "Plancherel measure".